# Why Chrome DevTools Protocol HeadlessExperimental.beginFrame does not return screenshot data for a long time(30s) in headless mode?

Tags: puppeteer, headless, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser, chrome-devtools-protocol

Headless brower is playing a video, and I want get every frame data.

Sometimes `frameData` can not get screenshot data but sometimes it work. And I don't know how to debugger this issue.

Here is my code:

```js
const frameData = await Promise.race([
     this.cdpSession.send("HeadlessExperimental.beginFrame", { screenshot: { format: "jpeg", quality: 80 } }),
     new Promise(resolve => timer = setTimeout(() => resolve(false), 30000))
]);
```

`frameData` can not get screenshot data because of the `30000ms` timer is trigger.

Please help me to deuuger this issue and find what reason cause this issue.